# Яйцо, лицо этимология

Tags: этимология

Существует ли в старославянском/русском слово "яйк"( -> яйце -> яйцо) по аналогии с лик -> лице -> лицо?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, не существует.

ЯЙЦО
Старославянское – аице.
В русском языке слово «яйцо» известно с XIV в.
В словаре Семёнова читаем:

> Старославянское слово образовано от общеславянского корня jaj,
>   который, по мнению исследователей, имеет индоевропейское
>   происхождение. Йотация (то есть звук j перед гласной) возникла на
>   общеславянской почве. В современном русском языке слово достаточно
>   распространено и имеет два значения:
>   1.      Заключенные в твердую оболочку овальной формы зародыши птиц, пресмыкающихся и яйцекладущих млекопитающих;
>   2.      Женская половая клетка. Родственными являются: Болгарское – яйце. Польское – jaje (яйцо). Производное: яичный.

http://evartist.narod.ru/text15/032.htm
Шанский :

> ЯЙЦО. Общеславянское суф. производное от *jaje, еще известного в ряде
>   совр. слав. яз. (ср. сербско.-х. jaja, в.-луж. jejo, польск. jaje и т.
>   д.) Йот — протетический, ранее было *aje.

https://lexicography.online/etymology/shansky/%D1%8F/%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%86%D0%BE

Цыганенко считает, что праславянское *aje развилось из и.-е.    *Ṑv-jo-m -название птицы. От него лат.*Ṑvum -яйцо, овис - птица (ср. авиация). Следовательно, яйцо первоначально значило "птичье".